# How to setup a WiFi 6E 6Ghz hotspot with Windows with AMD mainboard

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, hotspot

I have an MSU Tomahawk WiFi AMD  B650 that is WiFi 6E compatible. I want to use this to create a WiFi 6E 6Ghz hotspot but Windows will only let me chose 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz.

I have found [this site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059385/wireless/intel-wi-fi-6e-products.html) where it is shown how to install a driver for Intel products to activate the 6Ghz use.

Does someone know on how to make such a hotspot on Windows?

FYI, I currently have Windows 10 but I would upgrade if this is possible with Windows 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [underlying API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.tetheringwifiband?view=winrt-22621) for creating a hotspot/tether/WiFi access point only supports 2.4Ghz and 5GHz wifi bands in the current build of Windows 11 (22621):

> ### Fields
>
> - **Auto**   0    Specifies that the WiFi adapter is free to choose any band per internal logic.
> - **FiveGigahertz**  2     Specifies that the WiFi adapter should use only the 5 GHz band.
> - **TwoPointFourGigahertz**  1    Specifies that the WiFi adapter should use only the 2.4 GHz band.

---

However, the current [insider preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.tetheringwifiband?view=winrt-insider) build of Windows 11 (29541) has added a new **SixGigahertz** value. I don't have the preview build installed, so I'm not sure whether there's a matching option in the graphical interface yet. If you can't wait, there's a starter powershell example to launch the wifi tethering [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563418/7411885), though you'll have to feed it the Band settings.

---

Either way, the feature should be coming Soon™, at least for Windows 11. I couldn't find the same docs for Windows 10 builds, but I didn't search very far